# class member declaration is not accessible

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std ; 

class maths{
  int a;
  int b;
  void function(int b) { 
    a=1;
    while (a<=10) {
      cout<<a*b;
      a++;
    }
  }
};

int main() { 
  maths product;
  product.function(4); 
  // the 'product.function is showing some error saying the declaration is not accessible
  return 0; 
}
```

Comment: Please copy-paste your error message in your question (do not include it as an image)

Comment: It's not accessible because it's `private`.

Comment: As an aside, it will help you greatly if you indent your code correctly.  That makes it easier to read.

Comment: orrible title, please make it a bit relevant with the question

Comment: BTW, your class member variable `b` is not used.

Comment: Some compilers will give you very good advice about the problem: [https://ideone.com/GXgov0](https://ideone.com/GXgov0)  The following mesage should be easy to understand: ***prog.cpp:18:21: error: ‘void maths::function(int)’ is private within this context
   product.function(4);***

Answer (score 1):

In C++ class members default to private. Private members can only be accessed from within the class itself. You need to set the members to be public, like this:

```
class maths {
  public:
  // Everything after this label is now public
  int a;
  int b;
  // etc.

  // If you want to define some members as private later, do this
  private:
  int a_private_variable;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to solve this would be  to just replace the keyword `class` with `struct` as shown below.The use of `struct` makes all the member of the class `public` by default which means the user of the class can access them directly.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std ; 

struct maths{//NOTE THE KEYWORD STRUCT HERE
  int a;
  int b;
  void function(int b) { 
    a=1;
    while (a<=10) {
      cout<<a*b;
      a++;
    }
  }
};

int main() { 
  maths product;
  product.function(4); 
  // the 'product.function is showing some error saying the declaration is not accessible
  return 0; 
}
```